How to use these many conditions inside product?

I have tried all the way but I could not find a code for that line. It is consisting of three conditions.

c[n_,i_,j_]:=Product[If[k!=i&&k!=j&&j!=i,(x[k]-x[i])/(x[k]-x[j]),1],{k,0,n}];c[3,2,4] returns
((x[0]-x[2])*(x[1]-x[2])*(-x[2]+x[3]))/((x[0]-x[4])*(x[1]-x[4])*(x[3]-x[4]))

The arguments to c should be restricted
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Format[x[k_]] := Subscript[x, k]

c[n_Integer?(# > 1 &), i_Integer?(# >= 0 &), j_Integer?(# >= 0 &)] :=
 Product[If[k == i || k == j || j == i, 1,
   (x[k] - x[i])/(x[k] - x[j])], {k, 0, n}]

c will not evaluate with an invalid argument
{c[1, 2, 4], c[5, -2, 4], c[3, 2.5, 4]}

(* {c[1, 2, 4], c[5, -2, 4], c[3, 2.5, 4]} *)

With valid arguments
c[3, 2, 4]



The problem with OP is that it is not specified what should happen when conditions on n, i, j are not met. For instance, you made a choice to return c[2,1,1]=1. But for the same logic c[0, 1, 1] should return 1, isn't it?

@yarchik - As you indicated, it is not clear what was intended. You are free to interpret the intent as you wish.

In other answer, not all conditions were taken into account. Therefore the corrected function:
Clear[c]
c[n_Integer, i_Integer, j_Integer] := 
 Product[If[k == i || k == j, 1, (x[k] - x[i])/(x[k] - x[j])], {k, 0, n}] /; 
  i != j && n>1 && n >= i >= 0 && n >= j >= 0

